# How to prevent multiple objects from having the same reference?

Tags: java, object

We know that on using = in case of objects mean both will refer to same reference. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Let's say we have a class ComplexNumber. I don't want to allow anyone to initialize c like this.

```
class ComplexNumber { // x + iy
    int x; // Actual code is different. This is only for asking purpose
    int y;
    ComplexNumber(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber c) {
        this.x = c.x;
        this.y = c.y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d + %di", x, y);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }        
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComplexNumber a = new ComplexNumber(1, 2);

        // This is what I want to happen
        ComplexNumber b = new ComplexNumber(a);
        b.setX(b.getX() + 3); // This change will not affect a
        System.out.println(a); // unaltered

        // This is what I don't want to happen
        ComplexNumber c = a;
        c.setX(c.getX() + 4); // This change will affect a
        System.out.println(a); // altered
    }
}
```

I don't have any approach for this. All I can do is to not forget using new every time.

Comment: The easiest and best way is to mark both `x` and `y` as `final` so they cannot be changed.  As a result, you'll use new every time.  There is no other solution that prevents the issue, really.

Comment: @user16320675 That is exactly my question. I don't want anyone to do this, so I am asking a way to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Code:

```
class ComplexNumber { // x + iy
    int x; // Actual code is different. This is only for asking purpose
    int y;
    ComplexNumber(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber c) {
        this.x = c.x;
        this.y = c.y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d + %di", x, y);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }        
}

public class S75563667 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComplexNumber a = new ComplexNumber(1, 2);

        // This is what I want to happen
        ComplexNumber b = new ComplexNumber(a);
        b.setX(b.getX() + 3); // This change will not affect a
        System.out.println(a); // unaltered

        // This is what I don't want to happen
        ComplexNumber c = new ComplexNumber(a);
        c.setX(c.getX() + 4); // This change will not affect a
        System.out.println(a); // unaltered
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the getter and setter method, but you missed my question. You've written ComplexNumber c=new ComplexNumber(a); But what if someone writes ComplexNumber c=a; How can we prevent this from happening?